# multiprocessing - get_lock vs Lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

While searching information about shared multiprocessing variables I've noticed that there are two ways to update shared multiprocessing variable:

```
# Our shared variable
total_uploaded_files = multiprocessing.Value('I', 0)
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

# Method A
def my_multiprocessing_worker():
    global total_uploaded_files
    # do stuff ...
    with total_uploaded_files.get_lock():
        # increment shared counter
        total_uploaded_files.value += 1

# Method B
def my_multiprocessing_worker():
    global total_uploaded_files, lock
    # do stuff ...
    with lock:
        # increment shared counter
        total_uploaded_files.value += 1
```

What are the differences and which method should be preferred to implement multiprocessing counters for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `get_lock()` method of a `multiprocessing.Value` means that code using the object doesn't need to be concerned about the source of the `Lock` (since it could have been created automatically or was passed explicitly when the `Value` instance was created).

On the other hand, some might argue that Method B is more explicit and therefore consider it the better approach.

To muddle matters more, consider yet another, "hybrid" possibility:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

# Method C
@contextmanager
def locked(value):
    with value.get_lock():
        yield

def my_multiprocessing_worker():
    global total_uploaded_files
    # do stuff ...
    with locked(total_uploaded_files):
        # increment shared counter
        total_uploaded_files.value += 1
```

So, in my opinion, the bottomline is that ultimately it's just a matter of choice and preferred programming style...